# Windows Phone 8.1 Plugin: class not found

Tags: javascript, c#, cordova, windows-phone-8.1, cordova-plugins

i have the following problem with the following code:

**plugin.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        id="barcodescanner-plugin"
        version="0.0.1">
    <name>Barcode Scanner Plugin</name>
    <description>Cordova Barcode Scanner Plugin...</description>
    <author>XXX</author>
    <license>BSD</license>

    <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
         <feature name="BarcodeScanner">
              <param name="wp-package" value="BarcodeScanner"/>
         </feature>
    </config-file>

    <js-module src="www/BarcodeScanner.js" name="BarcodeScanner">
         <clobbers target="window.BarcodeScanner" />
    </js-module>

    <plattform name="wp8">
         <config-file target="Properties/WMAppManifest.xml" parent="/Deployment/App/Capabilities">
             <Capability Name="pointOfSale"/>
         </config-file>

         <source-file src="src/wp/BarcodeScanner.cs" />

         <framework src="lib/Windows.Devices.PointOfService.winmd" />
         <framework src="lib/WPCordovaClassLib.dll" />
    </plattform>
</plugin>
```

**BarcodeScanner.js**

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');

var BarcodeScanner = {
    result: "No Result available<br />",
    Enable: function () {
        try {
            var that = this;
            this.result += "Test 1<br />";
            exec(function () { that.result += "Test 2.1"; }, function (error) { that.result += "Test 2.2: " + error; }, "BarcodeScanner", "Enable", []);
            this.result += "Test 2<br />";
        } catch (e) {
            this.result += "Exception occured<br />";
            this.result += e.message + "<br />";
        }
    }
}

module.exports = BarcodeScanner;
```

**BarcodeScanner.cs**

```
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.JSON;

namespace WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands
{
    public class BarcodeScanner : BaseCommand
    {
        public void Enable(string options)
        {
            PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "Test... Test...");

            DispatchCommandResult(result);
        }
    }
}
```

**index.js**

```
var i = 0;

function updateOutputText() {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = i + ": " + window.BarcodeScanner.result;
    i++;
}

window.setInterval(updateOutputText, 1000);

(function () {
    "use strict";

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        window.BarcodeScanner.result += "Step 1<br />";

        // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
        document.addEventListener('pause', onPause.bind(this), false);
        document.addEventListener('resume', onResume.bind(this), false);

        window.BarcodeScanner.result += "Step 2<br />";
        window.BarcodeScanner.Enable();
    };

    function onPause() {
    };

    function onResume() {
    };
})();
```

and the following environment:

Cordova Tools for VS13
Cordova-Version: 5.0.0 and 4.1.2 (in VS13)

Target is a Panasonic FZ-E1 with Windows Phone 8.1 Embedded Handheld

The App prints the following when i call it:

> n: No Results available
>   Step 1
>   Step 2
>   Test 1
>   Test 2
>   Test 2.2: Class not found

if i move:

```
    <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
         <feature name="BarcodeScanner">
              <param name="wp-package" value="BarcodeScanner"/>
         </feature>
    </config-file>
```

to the wp8 segment it does not print Test 2.2

if i change:

```
exec(function () { that.result += "Test 2.1"; }, function (error) { that.result += "Test 2.2: " + error; }, "BarcodeScanner", "Enable", []);
```

to:

```
exec(function () { that.result += "Test 2.1"; }, function (error) { that.result += "Test 2.2: " + error; }, "BarcodeScanner.BarcodeScanner", "Enable", []);
```

or

```
exec(function () { that.result += "Test 2.1"; }, function (error) { that.result += "Test 2.2: " + error; }, "XXXBarcodeScanner", "Enable", []);
```

it also does not print Test 2.2

So i don't know exactly howto invoke now my C#-Method... I think BarcodeScanner is the right name because XXXBarcodeScanner is god damn wrong and BarcodeScanner.BarcodeScanner seems to show the same result. May you tell me what i do wrong? Because at the moment i'm really clueless.

Regards,
Steven Peter

Answer (score 0):

Got the shirt - I am sure....

Visual Studio has a nasty habit of really messing with your config.xml, especially the plugins.  I have also found the version to be randomly updated.

Open you config.xml in TEXT mode and make sure the barcode plugin reference is there.   Create a blank project, if you need to and add the plugin and then just check that they are the same.  I have had this also with the version info plugin, where it just wasn't there OR the version was wrong.

Also make a habit of double-checking your version numbers for android, win8, etc. as it sometimes does not update.

I really do like VS, but sometime it tests my patience.  Good Luck!

Comment: Hi, already tried before to use it in cordova itself with the same result... It is a wp8 only project so i don't think this could be the reason and yes i have the same issue with my config file but at the most of the times it deployes with the plugin.. But thanks i appreciate your help :)